# What is the order of order calculation in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shopping-cart-price-rules, tax, discount

What is order of order calculation means which is first calculate in order calculation process.

> -> Tax
>
> -> Discount
>
> -> Shopping cart rule
>
> -> Product price rule
>
> -> Tire prices

Please describe order of calculation.

Answer (score 0):

So In Below Image You Can see Calculation of Order Price.[image]